# Ubuntu 13.04 Eclipse 3.8.1 fresh install..cannot read Eclipse help files..ideas?

Tags: eclipse

I have recently setup a dual boot windows 7 /Ubuntu 13.04.

Problem:
I installed eclipse from the Ubuntu software center. Eclipse opens fine, but when i attempt to access the help i get a "server error 500"..

What i know:
the help file is located locally and read via the browser..

any ideas?..

nb.. novice linux user, happy to try anything to provide more data, ppls just be specific (ie assume i know zilch..)

update jun 30th..

Although not an answer to this question, i have patched a working solution by removing the version of eclipse supplied by the Ubuntu software center and installing from eclipse.org..
details at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2157452

thanks